# Removing Part of URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have recently removed a module from Magento that created vanity URL, for filtered searches. 
When I've removed this module its now using URL parameters for all filtered navigation pages.

I want to redirect all of these vanity urls to the same page without the vanity part of the URL.

An example of a URL that I want redirecting is:

> /hand-dryers/high-speed/shopby/brand-jet_towel-ultradry-magnum_multi_dri-dyson/handdryer_dryingtime_seconds-under_10_seconds/

Redirecting to

> /hand-dryers/high-speed

The way the module worked would be by adding the string "shopby" and then converting each parameter into a readable format.

I need a rewrite rule to re-direct all URLs that contain "shopby" to the same URL but with everything from "shopby" removed

I hope this makes sense. 
Look forward to hearing back from someone

Answer (score 1):

Should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (/.*)/shopby $1 [R=302,L]
```

After testing you can change the `302` to `301` to ensure the old URLs are pruned from search engine indexes.

Comment: Thanks Niels
Can you please explain the Rule?

Comment: Just a basic regular expression that catches all content *before* the literal /shopby part in a variable, ignores everything else, and then redirects to the caught block. This is rather basic knowledge, to understand it better I'd recommend reading some tutorials on rewriting.

Comment: Thanks
Appriciate the help

Comment: Hit the checkmark next to the answer to mark it as 'accepted solution' if it helped you  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/shopby/?.*$ $1/shopby [L]
```