# htaccess remove part of url and redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Trying to eliminate some duplicate urls. Currently I will get links like:

http://www.domain.com/item/2013/05/testing-title-example/catid/175

But its also created as:

http://www.domain.com/item/2013/05/testing-title-example/

I need to simply remove the /catid/# from all urls and be google friendly rewrites/redirects. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do?


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519637/removing-part-of-url-with-htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a simple 301 rule like this code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+)/catid/ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

`R=301` (permanent redirect) will tell search bots to cache the new URL.