# How to removing part of url by htaccess redirect rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

For some reasons a google addbot generates links like:

[https://batteryservice.bg/продукт/фенер-nitecore-mt40gt/batteryservice.bg](https://batteryservice.bg/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82/%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80-nitecore-mt40gt/batteryservice.bg)

I would like to remove this last part `/batteryservice.bg` and have something like:

[https://batteryservice.bg/продукт/фенер-nitecore-mt40gt/](https://batteryservice.bg/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82/%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80-nitecore-mt40gt/)

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801585/htaccess-remove-part-of-url-and-redirect) solution like : `RewriteRule ^(.+)/batteryservice.bg /$1 [R=301,L,NC]`  But this didn't worked for me.

Comment: Why does it not work?

Comment: It's just not redirecting. It loads the same url.

Comment: It seems to me like it should work. Figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Strangely enough this worked `RewriteRule ^(.+)/batteryservice.bg https://batteryservice.bg/$1 [R=301,L,NC]`

Answer (score 0):

This one worked, strangely enough `RewriteRule ^(.+)/batteryservice.bg https://batteryservice.bg/$1 [R=301,L,NC]`

Comment: I remember the original example you copied this from has a `RewriteBase`, maybe that affects it?

Comment: Yes, that's right, but i have it already in the .htaccess as it is a WordPress site and it is auto generated.